# Flutter App crashes on production on startup and through java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, flutter, classnotfoundexception

I am developing an app using flutter. The debug apk working fine but when I build apk for release, it crashes. I uploaded the app to playstore and found this in ANR/Crash reports page.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3029)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3266)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1957)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7099)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (AppComponentFactory.java:69)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1219)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3017)
```

My build.gradle file under android/app, content for reference.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1.1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.eduhomepro.students"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I am wondering what bug is causing the breakdown, all working fine in debug mode.

Comment: are you using minifyEnabled?? If yes, disable it and check the release apk

Comment: Not sure, where to check?

Comment: post your build.gradle file inside app folder under android directory

Comment: also post dependency list in pubspec.yaml

Comment: Just updated question and added build.gradle file

Comment: environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4
  intl: ^0.16.0
  table_calendar: ^2.2.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2

Comment: the file you posted comes under android directory, there is another build.gradle file under android/app/ folder. post that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207573/discussion-between-bikram-pahi-and-darish).

Comment: Either increase the `minSdkVersion` to 21 or add Multidex support: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you guys for all your efforts and support. I finally got the solution.

Actually I am trying to change the package name and change it from 
1) AndroidManifest.xml
2) build.gradle

But in my version, I need to update the `MainActivity.kt` under `app/src/main/kotlin`.

Now it is working fine.